# Cómo hacer un Select Between para dos fechas entre horas

Tags: mysql, sql

Mi problemática es la siguiente

[image: Base de datos]

Tengo mi base de datos registros y quisiera hacer una gráfica de las horas de llegada entre dos fechas, osease

De fecha A a B

Entre esos días a la 01:00 llegaron cuantos
y así con las 23 hrs

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Tiempos (cant int, hora varchar(5)); 
    WHILE v1 < 24 DO
        INSERT INTO Tiempos
            SELECT COUNT(registro.fi_registro) AS Llegada, CONCAT(v1, ':00') AS Horas FROM registro 
                WHERE registro.fi_registro BETWEEN 
                    CAST(CONCAT(date1, ' ', v1, ':00:00') AS DATETIME) AND 
                    CAST(CONCAT(date1, ' ', v1, ':59:00') AS DATETIME) AND
                    CAST(CONCAT(date2, ' ', v1, ':00:00') AS DATETIME) AND 
                    CAST(CONCAT(date2, ' ', v1, ':59:00') AS DATETIME);
        SET v1 = v1 + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT cant, hora FROM Tiempos;
    DROP TABLE Tiempos;
END
```

Bueno, logré hace esta función, pero solo me muestra entre las fechas de los Between, osea que hace lo siguiente, si pongo

CALL stats('2019-12-06', '2019-12-10') me aparece que a las 05:00 llegaron cuatro, pero cuando pongo CALL stats('2019-12-05', '2019-12-10') ya no aparecen, dan otros resultados.

[image: Resultado de consulta]

¿Como hacer que aparezca como digo? :c

Comment: Compartir código como imagen hace todo mucho más difícil para tratar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás haciendo un **BETWEEN** entre cuatro elementos, cuando generalmente se utiliza para acotar un rango (*si BETWEEN tiene más usos, que me corrijan*).

La idea que se me ocurre para solucionar tu problema es, por un lado, evaluar el rango de fechas (del 5 al 10); y, como añadido, buscar aquellas cuya hora (comando **HOUR**) sea igual al de tu bucle. Como **HOUR(datetime)** devuelve un int, no tendrías que castear nada en la comparación.

Creo que esto podría ayudar, reutilizando el código que ya tienes (*teniendo en cuenta que **date1** y **date2** son de tipo fecha; si no, castéalos antes de entrar en el bucle*):

```
    BEGIN
        DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Tiempos (cant int, hora varchar(5)); 
        WHILE v1 < 24 DO
            INSERT INTO Tiempos
                SELECT COUNT(registro.fi_registro) AS Llegada, CONCAT(v1, ':00') AS Horas
                FROM registro 
                WHERE registro.fi_registro BETWEEN date1 AND date2
                      AND HOUR(registro.fi_registro) = V1;
            SET v1 = v1 + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SELECT cant, hora FROM Tiempos;
        DROP TABLE Tiempos;
    END
```

Comment: Respuesta excelente, sólo agregué DATE_ADD(date2, INTERVAL 1 DAY) porque no me cuenta el segundo día como tal

Answer (score 1):

Creo que hacer un group por la hora podría ayudarte muchisimo, no necesitarías hacer el while ya que el group por hora te devuelve el conteo ordenado por horas.

Siguiendo tu código podría quedar algo así:

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Tiempos (cant int, hora varchar(5)); 
    INSERT INTO Tiempos 
        SELECT COUNT(registro.fi_registro) AS Llegada, CONCAT(HOUR(fi_registro),":00") AS Horas
            FROM registro 
            WHERE registro.fi_registro BETWEEN date1 AND date2
            GROUP BY HOUR(fi_registro);
    SELECT cant, hora FROM Tiempos;
    DROP TABLE Tiempos;
END
```

Pruebalo y me comentas, espero te sea util.  Saludos.

Comment: También pensé en eso. Pero quería el marguen completo, verás. voy a utilizar morris y esto sería el resultado de la data

Comment: El margen lo vas a definir en el between.